# How to remove from browsing history pages visited using a particular device?

Tags: google-chrome

I need to view browsing history of those pages which I visited using my computer only that was generated during a period of time when my computer and phone were synchronized. Is there a way to do it? Any help woul be very much appreciated.

Comment: Chrome  separates your history by device. Rather than try to go in to details, have you looked at your options on the history page? Unless I’m missing something, I remember it being pretty conspicuous.

Comment: Maybe it is me who is missing something, but what I see on the history page of my Chrome browser is pages visited with the use of several devices and no opportunity to display them separately.